# No entities found after EntityCollection(Of TEntity).Add execution

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-4

I am working on VB.NET project using Entity Framework 4.
When I create new entity and add it to context.EntityCollection, without calling context.SaveChanges I cannot found newly added entity in that collection.
I need to check for duplicate records before saving to database and it appears that only working solution is to store entities in some dictionary outside of whole EF-generated stuff for checking duplicate records.
Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking database directly before saving changes is possible solution.